# How to set covariance for Bivariate Logistic Distribution

Tags: image-processing

This is the logistic distribution of single random variable (taken from Wikipedia).

x = random variable
mu = mean of all random variables
s = variance.

[image]

Now, I want to do a Bivariate logistic distribution (having two random variables x1 and x2). My dataset is going to be image pixel values!

When I find the covariance of two random variables, it turns out to be a 2 x 2 square matrix but I need a single number! How to actually compute a bivariate model?

Answer (score 2):

The covariance of any multivariate distribution is always a matrix. Maybe it is of help to you to know what this matrix contains:

-In general, each entry i,j of the matrix gives you the correlation between the RVs i and j.

-So a diagonal element i,i will simply be the variance of the RV i.

-If RV i and j are independent, then the non-diagonal entry i,j is zero (they are uncorrelated). The reverse of this statement is not generally true, but it is for Gaussians iirc.

I don't know what you are trying to do, but perhaps the trace of the matrix or its determinant is of use to you?